# How to give an alert with label when user checks more than the prescribed seats in checkboxlist

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

Hi respected developers,

I am trying to develop **sample movie ticket booking** application.
I have 2 `checkboxlists` used for selecting seats. 
A user has to select seats up to the count where he already mentioned to select the seats from `dropdownlist` of previous `aspx page`.
Whenever user selects more than the seats mentioned, an `alert` using label has to be shown and the latest selected checked seat has to be unchecked automatically.
I got struck here.I could not move forward.Where I am doing wrong, somebody help me please.

```
public partial class TestSeat : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public int count;
    public static int i =0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
    }
    protected void chkboxlist2_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       int conver = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ddlseats"].ToString());
       // ddlseats is a dropdownlist selected number of seats by user before entering into this page.
       if (i >= conver)
       {
          chkboxlist2.SelectedItem.Selected = false;
          Response.Write("Not More than 4 seats can be selected");
       }
       else
       {
          if (chkboxlist2.SelectedItem.Selected)
          {
            i = i + 1;
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
if (i >= conver)
{
   ...
```

you want

```
if (value of chkboxlist2 > conver)
{
   Response.Write("Not More than " + conver + " seats can be selected");
   etc.
```

Comment: Hi wazz,thanks for responding.But my value of chkboxlist2 contains names of the seat.How could it be used for comparing with conver?